# Insert into mysql database multiple parameters with bindparam

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I use PDO to insert data into my database. I use bindparam but I'm getting this error. I can't figure out what is the problem. If anyone helps me thanks so much in advance!

> Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in script.php on line 3

here is my code

```
<?php
        $sql = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO contents VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, )");
        $sql->bindParam('iiissssssssssisiiii', NULL, $GroupID, $UserID, $Title, $Description, $tag_pointer, $Url, $arr['provider_name'], $Text, $arr['type'], $thumbnail, $arr['html'], 'NOW()', '0', getRealIP(), $Active, $Age, '0', '0');
        $sql->execute();
?>
```

Comment: put the params in an array and pass the array to the bind (or just pass it directly in the execute either works

Comment: if I pass them directly should not I worry about security or injection?

Comment: you're not passing them directly your still doing the ->prepare its just you'll pass them in as $sql->execute($paramarray); instead either works examples here http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Answer (score 1):

Move `NULL` into query

```
$sql = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO contents VALUES( NULL, ?, ...");
```

and then call your API functions according to manual page or at least [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Comment: Thanks now I'm getting different error 'PDOStatement::bindParam() expects at most 5 parameters, 19 given'

Comment: well, it's time to read a manual page for execute() for the driver you are using. it is not that hard.

Comment: yes it is thanks for help but you can at least tell me what causes the error so everyone will have an idea including me. thanks.

Comment: @ErdemEce You are mixing mysqli and PDO syntax, check the manual on `bindParam` for the parameters it expects: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: oo I was looking at mysqli manual in php.net. thanks! that helped!